# how to create Notification on different time of the Day?

Tags: swift

Notification want to be active every day at different times,Even when the app is fully closed
For example, 7 am and 1 pm and 9 pm

ios9
swift2
xcode7 
thanks

Comment: UILocalNotification with different time `fireDate`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create local notification with different fireDate

E.g :

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotificationalloc] init]; 
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create local notification and set fireDate property as per your requirement. eg.:

```
 let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Beacon detected"
        notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
        notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
```